# how can i see the current location on google map ,using obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

hii every one

how to see the current location in google map using obj c can any buddy suggest me some good tutorial for the same

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MapKit API. Take a close look at MKMapView.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205 After allocating an instance of MKMapView make sure to set the showsUserLocation property to YES

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationCoordinate2D location =
        [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];

NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",
        location.latitude,location.longitude);